# How do you deactivate a value of a custom field in wordpress post based on the number of posts that used it?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to make a custom field days which has 3 values- saturday, sunday and monday. Now if 10 posts are created that chose Sunday, then that value in the custom field will be greyed out for future contributors (you can't choose it anymore). Is there any way to do that? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: I wonder if you wouldn't get better answers to this type of question on a different forum? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, you have a few options. The easiest one would probably be to add an option with [`update_option()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_option/) and [`get_option()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/) on the [`save_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/) hook that counts the number of days chosen.

> Note: the `save_post` hook runs *after* the data is saved, (so the post meta is changed when you access it in that hook)

Something like this would get you started. You can add more validation and stuff, but the general idea would be to get the post_meta, and increase a tally if it's a valid day, and 10 don't already exist:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'so60062764_tally_num_days', 12, 1 );
function so60062764_tally_num_days( $post_id ){
    // Prevent Saving Relations for Autodrafts
    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return;

    // Does this post have a $day?
    if( $day = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'day_chosen', true ) ){
        // Yup, build valid days (prevent arbitrary values)
        $day = strtolower( $day ); // Normalize the string
        $valid_days = array( 'saturday', 'sunday', 'monday' );

        // Is the saved day in our list of valid ones?
        if( in_array($day, $valid_days) ){
            $current_num_days = absint( get_option( "num_$day" ) ); // absint converts strings to int, and false to 0

            // Did they somehow save this with 10 already existing?
            if( $current_num_days >= 10 ){
                // Yes, abort and revert
                delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'day_chosen' );
            } else {
                // update our "global tally"
                update_option( "num_$day", $current_num_days + 1 );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your meta box, you can just check the current global tally of days selected before you output the option. Here's a quick simple example, making use of PHP's [Ternary Operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) to save space:

```
echo '<select name="day_chosen">';
    $days = array( 'saturday', 'sunday', 'monday' );
    foreach( $days as $day ){
        $disabled = (get_option("num_$days") >= 10) ? 'disabled="disabled"' : '';
        printf( '<option %s value="%s">%s</option>', $disabled, $day, ucwords($day) );
    }
echo '</select>';
```